# Trouble with Minesweeper

Tags: python, minesweeper

Right now I am trying to get a 2D array(list of lists) into my minesweeper program in Python. However when I run it, it gives me a line 38 error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "F:\MINESWEEPER2.py", line 112, in <module>

    check_neighbours(reveal,board,bombs)

   File "F:\MINESWEEPER2.py", line 38, in check_neighbours

    board[index] = bombcount #copy the number of neighbouring bombs

   IndexError: list assignment index out of range).
```

Code:

```
 import string
 import os
 import random
 def check_neighbours(index, board, bombs):

#get the last digit in the index to check for left or right column positions
if index > 9:
    strindex = str(index)
    second = strindex[1]
else:
    second = 'a'

if index == 0:  #top left corner
    offsets=[1,10,11]
elif index == 9:    #top right corner
    offsets =[-1,9,10]
elif index == 90:   #bottom left corner
    offsets = [-10,-9, 1]
elif index ==99:    #bottom right corner
    offsets=[-11,-10,-1]
elif index > 0 and index < 9: #top row 
    offsets = [-1,1,9,10,11]
elif index >90 and index < 99:  #bottom row
    offsets = [-1,1,-9,-10,-11]
elif second == '9':     #Right side column
    offsets=[-11,-10,-1,9,10]
elif second == '0':     #Left side column
    offsets = [-10,-9,1,10,11]

else:
    offsets=[-11,-10,-9,-1,1,9,10,11]
bombcount = 0;
for i in offsets:   #check for bombs in all neighbour positions
    if index+i in bombs:
        bombcount+=1

board[index] = bombcount #copy the number of neighbouring bombs
if bombcount == 0:
    board[i][j] = ' '
    for i in offsets:   #Recursive function call for all neighbours
        if board[index + i] == '*':
            check_neighbours(index+i, board, bombs)


else:
    return



def print_reveal(board, bombs):
count = 0

rowcount = 0
for i in board:
    if count in bombs:
        i = 'B'
    print("| ", i, end=" ")
    if rowcount == 9:
        print("|")
        rowcount = 0
    else:
        rowcount += 1
    count += 1

board = []
bombs = []
for i in range(10):
 board.append([])
  for j in range(10):
    board[i].append('*')

for i in range(10):
 for j in range(10):
    print("|", board[i][j], end=" ")
print("|")
bombs = []
for i in range(10):


loc = random.randint(0, 99)
while loc in bombs:
    loc = random.randint(0, 99)
#board[loc] = 'B'
bombs.append(loc)


gameon=True
while(gameon):

choice = input("Do you want to pick a spot or flag a bomb? (pick or flag)")
if choice == 'flag':
    bombloc = int(input("Enter your guess for a bomb location: "))
    if bombloc >= 0 and bombloc < 100:
        if board[bombloc] != '*':
            print("already chosen!")
        else:
            board[bombloc] = 'F'



else:

    reveal = int(input("Enter your guess for an open spot: "))
    if reveal >= 0 and reveal < 100:
        if board[i][j] != '*' and board[i][j] != 'F':
            print("already chosen!")
        elif reveal in bombs:
            print("BOOOM!!!")
            gameon = False
        else:
            check_neighbours(reveal,board,bombs)



if '*' not in board:
    print("You WIN!")
    gameon = False

if(gameon):
    print_reveal(board,bombs)
print(bombs)
```

This is the output:

```
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * | * |
   Do you want to pick a spot or flag a bomb? (pick or flag)pick

   Enter your guess for an open spot: 30

   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "F:\MINESWEEPER2.py", line 112, in <module>

    check_neighbours(reveal,board,bombs)

   File "F:\MINESWEEPER2.py", line 38, in check_neighbours

    board[index] = bombcount #copy the number of neighbouring bombs

   IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I don't know what to do to fix this issue

I would really appreciate help on this

Comment: What line is the error at?

Comment: File "G:\MINESWEEPER2.py", line 114, in <module>
if board[reveal] != '*' and board[reveal] != 'F':
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If you have a line number with the error, specify which line has the error in the question.

Comment: line 114 is

if board[reveal] != '*' and board[reveal] != 'F':
                print("already chosen!")

Comment: No include it in the question.

Comment: Okay. I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you never initialize your board. In the early part of `print_reveal` you do: `board = []` (overwriting the `board` value passed as an argument), but then never fill `board` with anything.  Later, when you check what is in the spot the player picked, you get an `IndexError` from `if board[bombloc] != '*':` because `board` is still an empty list.

You need to decide if `print_reveal` should be creating the board or not. If not, just get rid of the `board = []` line (and make sure the argument passed in is appropriate). Otherwise, you should get rid of the confusing arguments and set up the board with appropriate values (perhaps `board = ["*"] * 100`) rather than using it uninitialized.

Comment: I took out the board = [] part in print_reveal. But how would I make the argument appropriate?

Comment: @user3533914: I'm not sure what the best structure for the program is. You need to think about where the board is coming from and where it gets passed. Part of your issue may be that you seem to be doing most of the work of your program in two functions with names starting in "print_", which would usually imply that they merely do output, rather than doing everything. See if you can refactor the actual gameplay parts into other functions and you'll probably have better luck.